# Turn off Suspend, Sleep, Hibernate for user (xfce4)

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, power-management

as the title is says, I want to disable all methods (buttons, commands, etc.) an unprivileged user have to turn a system into any standby-mode (sleep|hibernate|hybrid) under xfce4.

I found out that with a kioskrc file, we can disable to save user sessions.

```
# /etc/xdg/xfce4/kiosk/kioskrc
[xfce4-session]
SaveSession=NONE
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel confident you can foolproof this, but to start out I would:

1. Use Whisker menu and disable all commands in its settings
2. Remove action buttons from the panel
3. Configure the Power Manager to disable all buttons, sleep modes and lid closures etc. and copy that configuration (`.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-power-manager.xml`) to all users, owned by root and readable by users.
4. Restrict access to customize the panel in [kioskrc](https://wiki.xfce.org/howto/kiosk_mode)

Obviously, this only hinders things a bit from the Xfce UI, but all the time your users can open a shell or otherwise run arbitrary commands, you'd need to tighten this down on the OS level as well.

Comment: I believe you would primarily need to change polkit rules to remove the ability for users to call the functions. This may also include looking at the groups the user is a member of.

Answer (score 0):

You can do more things.

**SYSTEM**

First, I would recommend to disable hibernation and similar functions on the system:

```
systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

**FXCE configuration**

XFCE can be locked so that user cannot change its settings. If you customize the menus and then lock them you can remove the functions that you do not want to be present.

Lock is done with the following files:

1. File /etc/xdg/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-panel.xml

The line in XML file is changed from

to

"locked" and "unlocked" attributes to channel tag in the file tell xfce
that user is not allowed to change the XFCE settings.

2. File /etc/xdg/xfce4/kiosk/kioskrc

This file configures XFCE to work in kiosk mode where setting changes
are not allowed. The content of the file is:

```
[xfce4-panel]
CustomizePanel=none

[xfce4-session]
CustomizeSplash=NONE
CustomizeChooser=NONE
CustomizeLogout=NONE
CustomizeCompatibility=NONE
Shutdown=NONE
CustomizeSecurity=NONE

[xfdesktop]
UserMenu=NONE
CustomizeBackdrop=NONE
CustomizeDesktopMenu=NONE
CustomizeWindowlist=NONE
CustomizeDesktopIcons=NONE
```

To enable changes change the line in
/etc/xdg/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-panel.xml
and remove /etc/xdg/xfce4/kiosk/kioskrc. Then restart xfce and it will
not be locked any more.

**Screensaver**

If you also want that screen is never switched off, you can run a few commands after XFCE is started. You can easily add following commands to startup scripts.

```
/usr/bin/xset s noblank
/usr/bin/xset s off
/usr/bin/xset dpms 0 0 0
/usr/bin/xset -dpms
```

These are not exactly the steps you were asking for, but I think they can help you choose what to en/disable and how restrictive do you want to be.